# Kubernetes keeping old replicasets with running pods after deployments

Tags: kubernetes

Not sure why this is happening but we're seeing old replicasets with active pods running in our Kubernetes cluster despite the fact the deployments they are attached to have been long deleted (up to 82 days old). Our deployments have `spec.replicas` set to a max of 2, however we're seeing up to 6/8 active pods in these deployments.

We are currently running k8s version 1.14.6. Also below is a sample deployment

```
{
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "namespace": "default",
    "annotations": {
      "deployment.kubernetes.io/revision": "15",
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 2,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "app": "xxxxxxxx"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "xxxxxxxx",
            "image": "xxxxxxxx",
            "ports": [
              {
                "containerPort": 80,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ], 
            "resources": {},
            "imagePullPolicy": "Always"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "securityContext": {},
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler"
      }
    },
    "strategy": {
      "type": "RollingUpdate",
      "rollingUpdate": {
        "maxUnavailable": 1,
        "maxSurge": 1
      }
    },
    "minReadySeconds": 10,
    "revisionHistoryLimit": 2147483647,
    "progressDeadlineSeconds": 2147483647
  },
  "status": {
    "observedGeneration": 15,
    "replicas": 2,
    "updatedReplicas": 2,
    "readyReplicas": 2,
    "availableReplicas": 2,
    "conditions": [
      {
        "type": "Available",
        "status": "True",
        "reason": "MinimumReplicasAvailable",
        "message": "Deployment has minimum availability."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this? How?

Answer (score 1):

Changes to label selectors make existing pods fall out of ReplicaSet's scope, so if you change labels and label selector the pods are no longer "controlled" by ReplicaSet.

If you run `kubectl get pods <pod_name> -o yaml` where `<pod_name>` is a pod created by ReplicaSet, you will see owner reference.
However if you change labels and run the same command, owner reference is no longer visible because it fell out of ReplicaSet scope.

Also if you create bare pods and they happen to have the same labels as ReplicaSet, they will be acquired by ReplicaSet. It happens because RS is not limited to pods created by its template- it can acquire pods matching its selectors and terminate them as desired number specified in RS manifest will be exceeded.

If a bare pod is created before RS with the same labels, RS will count this pod and deploy only required number of pods to achieve desired number of replicas.

You can also remove ReplicaSet without affecting any of its Pods by using `kubectl delete` with `--cascade=false` option.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with Labels. There are no labels defined in your pod spec..

Answer (score -1):

A way to solve this is to set the "revisionHistoryLimit" to the maximum number of old replicasets that we want to keep. They are needed in case of rollback of a previous version, however usually this is not needed.
For instance we can set it to just 1 (or even 0), as per the .yaml configuration file below:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
# ...
spec:
  # ...
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1 # Default to 10 if not specified
  # ...
```

To manually remove already present old replicasets, it is possible to use this command:

```
kubectl delete replicaset $(kubectl get replicaset -o jsonpath='{ .items[?(@.spec.replicas==0)].metadata.name }')
```

These answers are taken from this related StackOverflow thread: [Clean up "Replica Sets" when updating deployments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255731/clean-up-replica-sets-when-updating-deployments) .