# How to delete orphaned replicasets with Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Not sure how but I've got numerous pods running that seem to be due to multiple repliacasets for each deployment.

This occurred after I did some heavy editing of multiple deployments.

Is there some easy way of deleting orphaned replica sets? As opposed to manually inspecting each, and determining if it matches with a deployment, and then delete it?

Answer (score 13):

`revisionHistoryLimit` is an optional field that specifies the number of old ReplicaSets to retain to allow rollback

By `default, 10 old ReplicaSets` will be kept, change it to one so you dont have more than one old replicaset.

[Offical Link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#revision-history-limit)

**Tested the field as below**

Created NGINX deployment updated multiple times and generate few replicaset as listed below

```
$ kubectl get all
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-854998f596-6jtth   1/1     Running   0          18s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   9d

NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx   1/1     1            1           6m20s

NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-59d5958c9f   0         0         0       4m5s
replicaset.apps/nginx-669cf47c4f   0         0         0       94s
replicaset.apps/nginx-6ff549666b   0         0         0       2m21s
replicaset.apps/nginx-854998f596   1         1         1       2m7s
replicaset.apps/nginx-966c7f84     0         0         0       108s
```

**Edit the running deployment and update revisionHistoryLimit field and set to zero** as `revisionHistoryLimit: 0`

```
$ kubectl edit deployments.apps nginx
deployment.apps/nginx edited
```

**Old Replica set are removed.**

```
$ kubectl get all
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-854998f596-6jtth   1/1     Running   0          52s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   9d

NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx   1/1     1            1           6m54s

NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-854998f596   1         1         1       2m41s
```

Answer (score 6):

A possible to manually remove old replicasets in a Kubernetes cluster is by running this command:

```
kubectl delete replicaset $(kubectl get replicaset -o jsonpath='{ .items[?(@.spec.replicas==0)].metadata.name }')
```

For further details, see also this thread, from which this answer is taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68274835/5538923 .

Answer (score 1):

you can edit your deployment and limit the history to 2 or 0

kubectl  -n master edit deploy you_deployment

```
spec:
   replicas: 2
   revisionHistoryLimit: 2
```

Comment: On a side note: We won't be able to see `revisionHistoryLimit` when we do `kubectl describe`.

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure how but I've got numerous pods running that seem to be due to multiple repliacasets for each deployment.

This is due to the revision history; the limit is set to 10 by default.
This is a safety measure to allow rollbacks to an old revision of a deployment.

Docs:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#revision-history-limit

If you want to clean up the old replicasets, you can delete them manually, or set a different limit.

Quoted from the docs:

> More specifically, setting this field to zero means that all old ReplicaSets with 0 replicas will be cleaned up. In this case, a new Deployment rollout cannot be undone, since its revision history is cleaned up.

If you don't particularly like to have to interactively edit files, you can use `kubectl patch` to update the revision history limit, e.g.:

```sh
# change me
NAMESPACE=default
DEPLOYMENT=nginx

kubectl \
   -n ${NAMESPACE} patch deployment.apps/${DEPLOYMENT} --type=json \
   -p '[{"op":"replace","path":"/spec/revisionHistoryLimit","value":0}]'
```